# How to evaluate whether a port should be closed or open?

Tags: port, firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall, pci-compliance

To meet PCI Compliance, I need to have a justification for every port that's open on Windows Server 2012 R2. I looked at my firewall, and there's a ton of rules. I started going through each rule and deciding if it should be closed or not, but I'm looking for a more efficient process.

My goals are to close ports without disrupting the live site in any way, and for ones I can't close, have a clear reasoning behind why I've left it open.

My first thought was to check what ports are being listened to using:
`netstat -aon`

But I'm not positive this is a comprehensive look at all the ports currently being used - for example, could there be processes that only use ports sometime and aren't listening on those ports other times?  What about ports used for scheduled activities, would those be listed here?

The way I see it, I need to figure out what firewall rules below are not being used by the server, and then be able to track down what service is using each rule I've left in the rules.

Here are my current active rules. Any recommendations on a process for doing this correctly?

- NSClient++ Monitoring Agent
- PRTG_Network_Monitor_Admin_Tool
- PRTG_Network_Monitor_Probe
- PRTG_Network_Monitor_Server
- PRTG_Network_Monitor_Server
- Visual Studio 2013 Remote Debugger Discovery (devenv.exe)
- Core Networking - Destination Unreachable (ICMPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Destination Unreachable Fragmentation Needed (ICMPv4-In)
- Core Networking - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP-In)
- Core Networking - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol for IPv6(DHCPV6-In)
- Core Networking - Internet Group Management Protocol (IGMP-In)
- Core Networking - IPHTTPS (TCP-In)
- Core Networking - IPv6 (IPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Multicast Listener Done (ICMPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Multicast Listener Query (ICMPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Multicast Listener Report (ICMPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Multicast Listener Report v2 (ICMPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Neighbor Discovery Advertisement (ICMPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Neighbor Discovery Solicitation (ICMPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Packet Too Big (ICMPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Parameter Problem (ICMPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Router Advertisement (ICMPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Router Solicitation (ICMPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Teredo (ICMPv6-In)
- Core Networking - Teredo (UDP-In)
- Core Networking - Time Exceeded (ICMPv6-In)
- File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)
- File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv6-In)
- File and Printer Sharing (LLMNR-UDP-In)
- File and Printer Sharing (NB-Datagram-In)
- File and Printer Sharing (NB-Name-In)
- File and Printer Sharing (NB-Session-In)
- File and Printer Sharing (SMB-In)
- File and Printer Sharing (Spooler Service - RPC)
- File and Printer Sharing (Spooler Service - RPC-EPMAP)
- File Server Remote Management (DCOM-In)
- File Server Remote Management (SMB-In)
- File Server Remote Management (WMI-In)
- Google Chrome (mDNS-In)
- Remote Desktop - Shadow (TCP-In)
- Remote Desktop - User Mode (TCP-In)
- Remote Desktop - User Mode (UDP-In)
- World Wide Web Services (HTTPS Traffic-In)
- Windows Communication Foundation Net.TCP Listener Adapter (TCP-In)
- Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)
- World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In)

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'm pretty sure the correct way to do something like this is "Block everything, unless you can justify opening it."  If you don't know enough to justify it, but you don't know if it's necessary, and you can't find it on a google search, then asking specific questions either here or on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) would probably be a good way to go.